# Sending the non-standard HTTP header X-XSS-Protection to xquery page (Using Marklogic server)

Tags: xquery, marklogic

The problem started when the Chrome browser throws this error:

"**Refused to execute a JavaScript script. Source code of script found within request**".

I already tried  meta tag with `http-equiv` attribute set to "`X-XSS-Protection`" and content attribute set to 0.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-XSS-Protection" content="0"/>
```

by placing in the head section to disable the option of preventing `xss` attack. But it is not working.

Help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you want:

xdmp:add-response-header("X-XSS-Protection", "0")

See [http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:add-response-header](http://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp%3aadd-response-header)

Comment: Thanks dan this function solved my problem.Thanks a lot.But why <meta http-equiv="X-XSS-Protection" content="0"/> inside body can't set header value.